# Attempting to make Coconut Pringles - dough too crumbly

Tags: dough, coconut, chips

not a cook here. Attempting to make coconut based "pringles".

here's my recipe:

```
3/4 cup coconut blended into essentially coconut butter
3/4 cup coconut flour
1 tbsp arrowroot powder 
1/4 tsp baking powder
1 cup water with 1/4 tsp salt
```

the idea was to run these through a pasta maker and cut out thin as possible circles that would crisp into pringly type chips. the dough is too crumbly. i'm assuming lack of starch? trying to make a coconut bacon type thing but in the shape of actual chips. http://www.phoneybaloneys.com/bacon/

any ideas on what i can do to make the dough less crumbly?

Comment: Um, your dough has no binder whatsoever. I don't know how commercial Pringles are made, but if you want to handle these like homemade dough, you'll need to get lots of raw protein into them. Starch won't help any. And the method used for commercial Pringles is not sure to help, because yours are so full of fat. Your "dough" is closest to a pie shell dough, out of any known homemade doughs. It's crumbly by nature.

Comment: ok thanks for the comment! Do you have any suggestions? eggs? whey protein? i thought the arrowroot powder was a binder? total noob here. thanks.